# Why status bar of my app hide automatically?

Tags: android, flutter, statusbar

I start a flutter app and I added some code to this app, and after that, when I run my app on an android device the status bar of my app hides automatically?

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.black,
        accentColor: Colors.amber,
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
          textTheme: ThemeData.light().textTheme.copyWith(
                title: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.amber,
                  fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
        ),
      ),
      title: 'Currency App',
      home: HomePage(),
      routes: {
        ExchangePage.routeName: (ctx) => ExchangePage(),
        GrowsPage.routeName: (ctx) => GrowsPage(),
        CurrencyPage.routeName: (ctx) => CurrencyPage(),
        ReorderListItemScreen.routeName: (ctx) => ReorderListItemScreen(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _portraitModeOnly();
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      appBar: AppBar(
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.amber),
        title: const Text('Currency App'),
      ),
      body: ImageCarousel(),
      drawer: DrawerCode(),
    );
  }

  void _portraitModeOnly() {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ]);
  }
}
```

This is my code, I searched various sites but couldn't find the right one, please help me, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same problem with my app.

A Full-Screen app, without a StatusBar.

You should try to find your loaded `Theme` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`

In my case, I was loading some `styles.xml` like this:

```
<style name="NormalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
     <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
     <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

I change this entry to **false**

```
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

The StatusBar is not going anywhere, the only reason you can't see it is that you have the `primaryColor` black, that will change the AppBar and the StatusBar to the same color, so it will look like it disappeared. What you can do if you'd like to change the StatusBar color independently is do this:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle( statusBarColor: Colors.lightBlue ));

    return MaterialApp()
```

Also, the 'title' property has been deprecated, the one inside of `appBarTheme: AppBarTheme()`
Use one of the 'headline'  https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextTheme-class.html

Comment: Hello Unbreachable, I think you got it wrong, I said status bar but you said AppBar, the Status bar where it shows the percentage of the battery, no AppBar thanks (-:

Comment: Oh oops, so you're saying that it somehow disappears? If you change the color of the primaryColor, the StatusBar and the AppBar both change to that color. Do you want them to be different?

Comment: Your answer is incorrect, the status bar is hidden, I changed the color but it didn't work (-:

Comment: You have the color black on it, it won't show with that color. If you change it to, let's say, grey, you will be able to see a darker shade on the statusBar